# Replacing a line in file with another files content, but placing content X lines after match

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a file to update with some new data. The new data inside another file. I have somewhat solved this myself.

However, the updated text needs to be 7 lines after my pattern match

Ive done an attempt by doing a grep -A 7 command, assign it to last_details.

This of course assigns the 7 lines to a variable (i guess a list), so it causes problems for the later sed.

```
last_details=$(grep -A7 ${last_string} /var/tmp/sym_links.ini.$$)
sed "/^${last_details}$/r ${tmp_symlinks_file_part_2}" /var/tmp/sym_links.ini.$$ > /var/tmp/sym_links.ini.$$.tmp2
```

So i want the output to go from

```
[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_10]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=
```

to

```
[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_10]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=

[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_11]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=
```

But instead i get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated address regex
```

Comment: Use xargs for this.. <yourcommandshere>|xargs and you will have that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too focused on HOW you want to do it and so missing info on WHAT it is you're trying to do. If you're just trying to add a new block of text after some other block of text in a file where all blocks are separated by blank lines then this is how to do that:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' -v str='[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_10]' '
    NR==FNR{new=$0; next} {print} $1==str{print new}
' newstuff file
```

For example using these input files:

```
$ cat file
[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_09]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=

[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_10]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=

[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_12]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=
```

.

```
$ cat newstuff
[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_11]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=
```

We can do:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' -v str='[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_10]' 'NR==FNR{new=$0; next} {print} $1==str{print new}' newstuff file
[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_09]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=

[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_10]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=

[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_11]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=

[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_12]
Path=/eniq/database/dwh_main_dbspace/dbspace_dir_10/main_10.iq
Lun_ID=
Size=121668
Type=fs
Link=
Disk=
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\[DWH_DBSPACES_MAIN_10\]/!b;:a;N;s/\n/&/7;Ta;r insertFile' file
```

Focus on the line to be matched. Append seven lines by introducing a loop, then append the required file. The pattern space will be printed before the inserted file is placed in the output stream.

N.B. The introduced loop utilises the  fact that when a line is appended to the pattern space, a newline is prepended. Thus a proposition can be manufactured by replacing the newline by itself (or not) and using the test `t` for a successful substitution or in this case a `T` for the opposite.